# MySQL group by contains

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following query:

```
select *, group_concat(tags.tag_name separator ',') as tags from games
left join game_info using(game_id)
left join game_tags using(game_id)
left join tags on(tags.tag_id = game_tags.tag_id)
group by games.game_id;
```

Is there a way for me to filter the results where the group has a particular value?

I could add a having, but that doesn't seem very optimal:

```
select *, group_concat(tags.tag_name separator ',') as tags from games
left join game_info using(game_id)
left join game_tags using(game_id)
left join tags on(tags.tag_id = game_tags.tag_id)
group by games.game_id
having tags like '%puzzle%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you filter on the end result (`tags`), a more efficient statement is not likely. Variations on the statement are possible and you could test them to see if they are more efficient.

> **Remark**: In you `SELECT` there is a `*` without any `GROUP BY` function. This will result in either random return of a `*` value list, a long list of repetitions of `tags` values or no grouping at all (error on the query). Apply a function to all returned column values so you are in control of which value is returned.

*A possible alternative query:*

First select all the game_ids which do have your %puzzle%

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name LIKE '%puzzle%'
```

Join this back on games to get all the game_ids where game_id has %puzzle% and other values:

```
SELECT game_id,group_concat(tags.tag_name separator ',') as tags
FROM games gs
INNER JOIN game_tags gt ON gs.game_id=gt.game_id
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name LIKE '%puzzle%') q
    ON gt.tag_id=q.tag_id
GROUP BY gs.game_id;
```

Since the HAVING would have filtered any not matchable data, an INNER JOIN can be used instead of a LEFT JOIN, often speeding up the query a bit.

Using the `*` **remark** from above, the table `game_info` can be removed from the query since it would not do anything in the result.